# Insert Numerical 0 in front of current value in Mysql DB column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a a MySQL database the information I uploaded to populate the database is from a CSV file. The CSV file has a numerical value eg 9875637892. As I have over 2000 rows in the CSV the leading 0 is missing. I cannot for obvious reasons go thru 2000 plus records to add leading zero I need to have 09875637892 in each row.

Is there a way I can run a SQL string to add the 0 in front of 9875637892 from SQL?

Comment: What is the datatype of that column? Bigint? varchar?

Comment: @SalmanA  varchar

Answer (score 2):

Numeric values do not have leading zeros.  If the value in the CSV file does, then change the datatype to a string and re-import the data.

If that is not possible, then make the change in place:

```
alter table t modify col varchar(255);

update t
    set col = concat('0', col);
```

If the value is already a string, you can just run the `update`.

Answer (score 2):

[L(-eft)PAD](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_lpad.asp) seems an apropriate solution:

```
-- simple test:
SELECT LPAD('9875637892', 11, '0');

===========================
Number of Records: 1
===========================
LPAD('9875637892', 11, '0')
---------------------------
09875637892

-- update table:
UPDATE yourtable
SET yourcolumn = LPAD(yourcolumn, 11, '0');
```

(assuming 11 digits max/to fill up)